# This query (SELECT JOIN SUM ON) worked well before on another project however now it doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The below query worked fine on another project (SQL), however now it seems to give no results and i do not get why. Have search allready for hours on the web for solutions.
I have 2 tables, one GOALS (id_goals, season, player, goalsscored, assists, team) and another PLAYERS (id_player, name, and some more fields not important for this matter). id_player from PLAYERS is used in player field in GOALS. Now i want to display the name of the players and the total goals they have scored as well as the total assists they have made in a certain season for a certain team and this is the query I am using (but does not work anymore):

```
mysql_select_db($database_check_mag, $check_mag);
$query_getPosts = "SELECT id, tot_goals, player_name, tot_assists FROM
(SELECT g.player id, SUM(g.goalsscored) tot_goals, SUM(g.assists) tot_assists,
g.season, s.name player_name, s.id_player FROM goals g JOIN players s ON 
g.player = s.id_player WHERE g.season = 20132 AND g.team = 39   
GROUP BY g.player) sums GROUP BY id ORDER BY tot_goals DESC";
```

Can somebody help me and tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you ran this query manually in MySQL? If it doesn't return anything, then your "WHERE" clause is excluding your possible matches somehow. Probably because there is no "20132" season.

Comment: Does "does not work anymore" mean "does not show an error message, but shows an empty result? If so, are you sure there is data for `g.season = 20132 AND g.team = 39`?

Comment: Thanks that helped already. I am still learning soo much. Yes when i run the query manualy in Mysql, which i didn't do as did not think about that, it return the results I want... mmmm it is thus in the rest of the code! I will look further now. If i don't get it I will ask further info. At least now i know the query works fine :-)

Comment: Found it! Had deleted the query and fetch itself... so simple but this took me hours! I thought my query was wrong. Thank you for such a simple answer which got me back on track, must be too late :-)